# Search a list of phrases against a word-list and count the number of occurances

Tags: c#

The problem is simple... 
Given:

-> a list of foul-words, say List1.

-> a List of strings (or phrases) to search for these foul-words, say List2

Desired output:
Count of phrases which matched at least one of the foul-words.

Sample:
**List1**: "cat", "dog", "mouse", "Nice animal"
**List2**: "A cat is good". "a dog is bad", "cat and dog are good", "Nice animal", "Hello", "Hello mouse", "This is bad"

Output:
5 phrases contain at least 1 foul word.

What I did:

```
int sum = list1.Sum(s => list2.Count(t => t.Contains(s)));
```

This takes about 38 seconds for a foul-word list of 5600 phrases, and about 4000 strings to search in. (quad-core, 4 GB RAM)... WAYYYYYY TOO SLOW!

I have looked around for solutions or algorithms that might exist for this... Could not find any.

Even if someone can point me in the right direction, by naming an algo, showing a code snippet, or just pointing a finger (!!), it would be great!

Comment: I have no idea if this will actually help, but you could try to compile a regex out of all the foul words (a single regex containing them all, and compile it), than run it against the phrases. I'm just guessing that a compiled regex is faster than your linq query.

Comment: [Inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) or [Search engine indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing)

Comment: Maybe using regular expressions would be more efficient.

Comment: @filipko RegEx would be really slower than String.Contains because has different purpose and different optimizations. To match exact word string.Contains will be always faster.

Comment: Here is a nice list of possible approaches to [word list matching in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516646/scan-text-and-check-whether-it-contains-word-from-specified-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be more efficient since `Any` breaks as soon as possible:

```
int contains = phrases.Count(p => foulWords.Any(fw => p.Contains(fw)));
```

Your approach is also not optimal since your starting point is `List1`(`foulWords`) so you need the sum of each count which is inefficient. The correct result must be between 0(no matching foul-word) and `phrases.Count`(all phrases contain a foul-word). So the starting point should be `phrases`.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/vK17gi)

> Q: Could you also help me modify the above code to also give me INDEX
>   of the phrase in the list?

Yes:

```
var wordIndexes = phrases.Select((phrase, index) => new { phrase, index })
    .Where(x => foulWords.Any(fw => x.phrase.Contains(fw)));

foreach (var wordIndex in wordIndexes)
    Console.WriteLine("Word: {0} Index: {1}", wordIndex.phrase, wordIndex.index);
```

Result:

```
Word: A cat is good        Index: 0
Word: a dog is bad         Index: 1
Word: cat and dog are good Index: 2
Word: Nice animal          Index: 3
Word: Hello mouse          Index: 5
```

Comment: +1 - was about to post pretty much the same: var count = phrases.Count(p => foul.Any(tf => p.Contains(tf)));

Comment: @Tim - Could you also help me modify the above code to also give me INDEX of the phrase in the list?
So the output would be: 5 (0,1,2,5,....)

I simply changed COUNT to WHERE and selected... This is again slow... What could I be doing wrong?!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, again!

I think I need LINQ lessons badly... :-|